# App drawer on stock Android not alphabetized

Tags: app-drawer

I have a Nexus 4 with stock Android and no modifications. I installed a flashlight app and for some reason it is first in my app drawer despite it starting with a "f" and not an "a". As a developer I find this intriguing. Does anybody know how this developer managed to put his app first in the drawer or is this some type of bug?
[image: app drawer screen shot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say for sure, but there's probably a zero-width non-breaking space, or some other invisible or unprintable character, at the start of the label, causing it to sort ahead of normal characters.

Comment: I tend to agree with Dan. I also note that [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.surpax.ledflashlight.panel) has a worrying number of app permissions for a simple flashlight app. Why, for instance, does it need access to change system settings or to read external storage? I recommend you dump it and get something else, and not just for the annoying end-around of alpha sorting.

Comment: @AlEverett good point

Comment: I had the same problem with the same app. I uninstalled it after reading Al's post.